# Rust's `matches!` analog in Scala

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

I have the following code:

```scala
stageState.get match {
  case Idle(_) => true
  case _ => false
}
```

In rust I can simplify it to this:

```rust
matches!(stageState.get(), Idle(_))
```

Is there an analog in Scala for that?

Comment: `stageState.get.isInstanceOf[Idle]`?

Comment: @GaëlJ this does work for `Idle(_)`, but does not for other variant. Here is the example https://scastie.scala-lang.org/kGXVkPUXRfCgGtpcFaPpNA

Comment: for `object`s (which is what you get in an `enum` case with no parameters), you need to use `.type` to refer to the type rather than the instance. `isInstanceOf[Status.Complete.type]`.

Comment: You could write something very similar using an extension method and partial functions

Comment: Following up on @GaëlJ's comment: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/stefanobaghino/43bHBt3ISYSKxvr7Cwyrgw/2

Comment: Assuming `stageState` is an `Option` (or similar), `stageState.exists(_.isInstanceOf[Idle])` or `stageState.exists(_.isInstanceOf[Complete.type])` might be more idiomatic (an empty `stageState` would be false in either case)... GraalVM would likely inline that to the point that it would become allocation free.

Comment: `Idle.unapply(stageState.get).isDefined`? (Quite often matching delegated to extractor method which often - but not always - returns `Option`). I believe that you could have a direct counterpart implemented with a macro that rewrites into pattern-matching and/or a partial function... but only if whatever is rewritten would typecheck even without `case` and `=> ...`. If `stageState` is `Option` then I think it would be better to have `stageState.collect { case Idle(_) => () }.isDefnied`.